# ASP.NET core confirmation and migration with azure prroblem

Tags: reactjs, azure, asp.net-core

Struggling the paste of connection string from. Azure ADO.NET connection string in appsettings.json file and also struggling migration settings in startup file. And another related file.

Comment: Hi, you would need to provide more details. What did you try, do you have some code to show etc... Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info of how to ask a question in order to get some proper answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying, actually I didn't start firewall that's why I can not see out put but now I can